# How to have DropWizard JUnit App Rule definition use startup information from a docker rule?

Tags: java, docker, junit, dropwizard

The general problem I am trying to solve is this. I have a solution, but it's very clunky, and I'm hoping someone knows of a more orderly one.

Dropwizard offers a JUnit TestRule called DropwizardAppRule, which is used for integration tests. You use it like this:

```
@ClassRule
public static final DropWizardAppRule<MyConfiguration> APP_RULE = new DropwizardAppRule(MyApplication.class, myYmlResourceFilePath, ConfigOverride("mydatabase.url", myJdbcUrl));
```

It will start up your application, configuring it with your yml resource file, with overrides that you specified in the constructor. Note, however, that your overrides are bound at construction time.

There are also JUnit rules out there to start up a Docker container, and I'm using one to start up MySql, and a JUnit RuleChain to enforce the fact that the container must start up before I launch my Dropwizard application that depends on it.

All that works great, if I'm willing to specify in advance what port I want the MySql container to expose. I'm not. I want these integration tests to run on a build machine, quite possibly in parallel for branch builds of the same project, and I would strongly prefer to use the mechanism where you ask Docker to pick any available port, and use that.

The problem I run into with that, is that the exposed container port is not known at the time that the DropwizardAppRule is constructed, which is the only time you can bind configuration overrides.

The solution I adopted was to make a wrapper JUnit Rule, like so:

```
public class CreateWhenRunRuleWrapper<T extends ExternalResource> extends ExternalResource {
    private final Supplier<T> wrappedRuleFactory;
    private T wrappedRule;

    public CreateWhenRunRuleWrapper(Supplier<T> wrappedRuleFactory) {
        this.wrappedRuleFactory = wrappedRuleFactory;
    }

    public T getWrappedRule() {
        return wrappedRule;
    }

    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        wrappedRule = wrappedRuleFactory.get();
        wrappedRule.before();
    }

    @Override
    protected void after() {
        wrappedRule.after();
    }
}
```

This works, allowing me to construct the DropWizardAppRule class in the before() method, but is quite obviously outside JUnit's design intent, as shown by the fact that I had to locate it in the org.junit.rules package, in order to empower my class to be able to call the before() and after() methods of the late-created Rule.

What would be a more orderly, best practice way to accomplish the same objective?

Answer (score 0):

2 Options we came up with:

The hacky solution is to use static {} which executes the code after spinning up the container but before initialising the dropwizard instance:

```
public static final GenericContainer mongodb = new GenericContainer("mongo:latest").withExposedPorts(27017);
static {
    mongodb.start();
    System.setProperty("dw.mongoConfig.uri", "mongodb://" + mongodb.getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + mongodb.getMappedPort(27017));
}

@ClassRule
public static final DropwizardIntegrationAppRule<Config> app1 = new DropwizardIntegrationAppRule<>(Service.class);
```

The second option is cleaner and much like yours.

```
private static final MongoDContainerRule mongo = new MongoDContainerRule();

private static final DropwizardIntegrationAppRule<Config> app = new DropwizardIntegrationAppRule<>(Service.class);

@ClassRule
public static final RuleChain chain = RuleChain
        .outerRule(mongo)
        .around(app)
```

MongoDContainerRule is like your wrapper but it also sets the right port through system properties.

```
public class MongoDContainerRule extends MongoDBContainerBase {

    private static final GenericContainer mongodb = new GenericContainer("mongo:latest").withExposedPorts(27017);

    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        mongodb.start();
        System.setProperty("dw.mongoConfig.uri", "mongodb://" + mongodb.getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + mongodb.getMappedPort(27017));
        System.setProperty("dw.mongoConfig.tls", "false");
        System.setProperty("dw.mongoConfig.dbName", DB_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void after() {
        mongodb.stop();
    }
}
```

The container will expose mongodb on a free port. mongodb.getMappedPort(internalPort) will return it. System.setProperty("dw.*") injects values into the dropwizard config.